# asp.net mvc5 ajax with jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am building a website online store I want when click the add to cart button then number of commodity to be stored in a session  with ajax and the message "saved" is displayed But this don’t work and don't display "saved"

View :

```
<p>
    <img src="images/a.jpg">
    <input type="text" id="1232542">
    <button class="art-button">add to cart</button></p><p id="resolt">
</p>
```

jQuery :

```
$('#btntaeid1').click(function () {
    var number = $("#1232542").val();
    $("#resolt").html('loding...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '@Url.Action("Main", "AddToCart")',
        data: { 'Number': number },
        success: function(aaaa) {
            $("#resolt").html(saved);
        }
    });
});
```

Session class

```
public class SessionCommodity
{
    private string NumberCommodity;

    public SessionCommodity()
    {

    }
}
```

AddToCart  Action in Main controler

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(int Number)
{
     var s = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["cart"] as List<SessionCommodity>;
     if (s == null)
     {
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["cart"] = s;
     }
     s.Add(new SessionCommodity {NumberCommodity = Number });
     return Json(new {Added = true});
}
```

Comment: Your entire question title is just tags of technologies that you are (presumably) using. Can you edit this to clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: More to the point - can you see the network request in your console? Are there errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the ajax method when the button which has id of "btntaeid1" clicked. But your html content hasnt got that element. Either add the id attribute to the button element or change the click function to be fired when something exist is clicked.

View:

```
<p>
    <img src="images/a.jpg">
    <input type="text" id="1232542">
    <button id="btntaeid1" class="art-button">add to cart</button></p><p id="resolt">
</p>
```

or the jquery part according to your post:

```
$('.art-button').click(function () {
    var number = $("#1232542").val();
    $("#resolt").html('loding...');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: '@Url.Action("Main", "AddToCart")',
        data: { 'Number': number },
        success: function(aaaa) {
           $("#resolt").html(saved);
        }
    });
});
```